# have plot points coloured on a spectrum in R

Tags: r, colors, plot

I have a list of points that I want to play on a graph in R. In a bid to have 3 levels of information (X axis, Y axis and another) I want to plot the points on a graph and colour them on a scale for the 3rd variable. I have a percentage value for each point that I want displayed as the third variable (Z). So if A has a Z value of 0.95, I want it a bright red, but as B only has Z = 0.65, I want it dull red heading to blue. Values go from NA (which should be blue I suppose) to 0.99 (bright red).

Sample data:

```
1   1   0.02937715
2   1   0.05872889
3   1   0.08802983
4   1   0.11725462
5   1   0.14637799
6   1   0.17537475
7   1   0.20421981
8   1   0.23288821
9   1   0.26135518
10  1   0.28959607
```

The third column gives the Z values.

Comment: Which plotting system are you using? Base graphics, lattice, or ggplot2?

Comment: base right now, but I dont mind.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some reproducible data to play with would be helpful:

```
DF <- expand.grid(x=1:100, y=1:100)
DF$z <- abs(sin(DF$x/34) * cos(DF$y/22))
```

`x` and `y` are a grid from 1 to 100; `z` ranges between 0 and 1 (the function is nothing in particular, just something that stays between 0 and 1 and doesn't have extremely simple structure).

## Base graphics

```
plot(DF$x, DF$y, col=rgb((colorRamp(c("blue", "red"))(DF$z))/255), pch=19)
```

[image]

## ggplot2

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(DF, aes(x, y, colour=z)) +
  geom_point(shape=19) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="blue", high="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Brian, sorry about the delay in replying, got quite busy, but I've added sample data. Ill work on what you've given me so far anyway.

Comment: I assume this answer doesn't help since you put a bounty for more detail, but I'm not sure what more detail you want. Aside from possibly changing variable names (which I don't know what yours are since they aren't in the example), these should work on your data as written.

Comment: no no it does help. I just gave a bounty as I really appreciate the quality of your answer.

Comment: That's... not really what bounties are meant for. But Okay.

Comment: @PaulMurray Well, that is one use of the bounty system: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176579/awarding-reps-for-excellent-questions-non-bounty-answers It is a different reason than the one that was selected (which is why I was initially confused), but it is a valid reason.